# Downloading CSV from website by clicking a button

Tags: c#, winforms

There is a site (the site is in Hebrew, will add the link below) that allows the client to download a CSV file by pressing a key.
I want that by pressing a key on my program, the file will be downloaded to a specific folder. Also, the website has the option to reveal the drop-down menu, I need to download every item in drop-down separately.
The Html on the website:

```
<span class="export-container" onclick="funds.exportToCSV()"><span class="icon icon-excell"></span><span>יצוא לקובץ אקסל</span></span>
```

Link to the website:
https://www.bizportal.co.il/mutualfunds

I tried to use a web browser and then click on the button, that asks me where to save the file.

```
var links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");
        foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
        {
            if (link.GetAttribute("className") == "export-container")
            {
                link.InvokeMember("click");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: look into UIPath. It is simple to do stuff like this in that

Comment: I tried to search for that funds.exportToCSV() but couldn't find it...